# why is there an 'equal' and opposite reaction if the force depends on the momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If you have a large mass and a small mass that collide, the large mass reacts according the smaller mass's momentum and vise versa. For it to be consider 'equal' doesn't that mean they have to feel the same amount of repulsion?

Note: I know I have a misunderstanding, I am not challenging anything, just looking for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do feel the same force. If you look at the collision in the center of mass frame, you see the heavy object moving towards you slowly, and the light object very rapidly. After the collision, they reverse directions, but the heavy one is still slow and the light one is still fast.

So the light one's velocity changed by a LOT more - although the change in momentum of the two objects is the same.

There is no contradiction - just a failure of intuition. You say "the force depends on the momentum", but that's not really true. The change in momentum is given by $\Delta p = m \Delta v = F \Delta t$; as I sketched above, the force (and duration of collision) necessarily is the same for both objects, as is the change in momentum; but for the light object, this change of momentum results in a big change in velocity.